# Need to play mp3 and .wav files in c# without using com dll's

Tags: c#, naudio

I need to play the audio files like mp3 and .wav using c#. I don't want to use the com dll's and I need some functionality like to set the current time and end time of the file to play. etc.

Need some sample exmaples for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To play audio using C# at some point the managed code will need to call into unmanaged APIs. [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) provides wrappers for [four different Windows audio playback APIs](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/naudio-audio-output-devices.html). WaveOut would be the most appropriate choice for you, since it is not COM based.

To decode MP3, you have a choice of using the codecs that come with Windows or trying to find a fully managed MP3 decoder. NAudio provides interop wrappers for two different Windows MP3 decoders - the Fraunhofer ACM codec that comes with Windows XP and above and the DirectX Media Object decoder that comes with Windows Vista and above. If you want a fully managed MP3 decoder, you can try [NLayer](http://nlayer.codeplex.com) which is a port I made of [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) to .NET, although its public API doesn't currently allow it to slot neatly into an NAudio app.